Hay I just wrote the Software Defined Radio tag
The problem is that I have never been paid to work on SDR nor have I ever written code to do SDR.
So maybe someone more experienced with me should visit the tag and write a better definition (plain text), or maybe write a little primer (with LaTeX or pics) in the User Guidance.
But the tag needs a definition, in my opinion.  So I wrote a crude little top-level not-very-deep definition.  Please improve it.
